# $\sum a_k$ converges iff $\sum a_{2k}+a_{2k+1}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

A more clear statement:

Suppose $a_k \to 0$.  The series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ converges iff $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (a_{2k}+a_{2k+1})$ converges.

I have been able to prove the forward direction.  I'm stuck on backward direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $\sum_{k\ge 1}(a_{2k}+a_{2k+1})=L$; clearly we want to show that $\sum_{k\ge 1}a_k=L+a_1$. Let $\epsilon>0$; there is an $m_\epsilon\in\Bbb N$ such that $$\left|L-\sum_{k=1}^n(a_{2k}+a_{2k+1})\right|<\epsilon$$ whenever $n\ge m_\epsilon$. There is also an $m_\epsilon'\in\Bbb N$ such that $|a_n|<\epsilon$ whenever $n\ge m_\epsilon'$.

Now consider a partial sum $\sum_{k=1}^na_k$. Suppose first that $n$ is odd; say $n=2m+1$. Then $$\sum_{k=1}^na_k=a_1+\sum_{k=1}^m(a_{2k}+a_{2k+1})\;,$$ so if $m\ge m_\epsilon$ we have

$$\left|a_1+L-\sum_{k=1}^na_k\right|=\left|L-\sum_{k=1}^m(a_{2k}+a_{2k+1})\right|<\epsilon\;.$$

Now suppose that $n$ is even; say $n=2m$. Then $$\sum_{k=1}^na_k=a_1+\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}(a_{2k}+a_{2k+1})+a_{2m}\;,$$ so if $m-1\ge m_\epsilon$ and $n\ge m_\epsilon'$ we have

$$\begin{align*}
\left|a_1+L-\sum_{k=1}^na_k\right|&=\left|L-\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}(a_{2k}+a_{2k+1})-a_n\right|\\
&\le\left|L-\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}(a_{2k}+a_{2k+1})\right|+|a_n|\\
&<\epsilon+\epsilon\\
&=2\epsilon\;.
\end{align*}$$

In all cases, therefore, if $n\ge\max\{2m_\epsilon+1,m_\epsilon'\}$, then

$$\left|a_1+L-\sum_{k=1}^na_k\right|<2\epsilon\;,$$

and it follows that $$\sum_{k\ge 1}a_k=a_1+L\;.$$

Comment: Hello Brian. I have a basic question, which I can not figure out. How does $n\ge\max\{m_\epsilon,m_\epsilon'\}$ ensure that $m\geq m_\epsilon$ or $m-1\geq m_\epsilon$? Also, could you provide a hint or sketch on how to prove the converse? That would be much appreciated.

Comment: @psie: Looks like I slipped up there at the end: we need to take $n\ge 2m_\epsilon+1$ to ensure that $m\ge m_\epsilon$. (This works for both odd and even $n$.) For the forward direction note that the sequence of partial sums of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty(a_{2k}+a_{2k+1})$ is a subsequence of the sequence of partial sums of $\sum_{k=2}^\infty a_k$.

Comment: An explanation of the downvote would be helpful: if there is actually an error, I want to correct it.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted, I voted up!

Comment: @psie: Not to worry: I figured that yours was the upvote. And thanks very much for catching the error.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Because $\sum (a_{2k}+a_{2k+1})$ converges, the sequence of partial sums of this series is Cauchy.

Conclude from this that the sequence of partial sums of the series $\sum a_n$ is Cauchy.  For odd $m$ and/or even $n$, where $m\lt n$,  we will need the fact that for large $m$ and $n$, the terms $a_m$ and $a_n$ have absolute value close to $0$. This part follows from the assumption that the $a_n$ have limit $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exists $n_0$ such that, for all $m>n$,
$$
\left|\sum_{k=n_0}^ma_{2k}+a_{2k+1}\right|<\varepsilon.
$$
There also exists $n_1$ such that $|a_k|<\varepsilon$ if $k\geq n_1$. Let $n=\max\{n_0,n_1\}$.

Then, for any $m>2n$ and a proper $c\in\{0,1\}$,
$$
\left|\sum_{k=2n}^ma_k\right|=\left|\left(\sum_{k=n}^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor} a_{2k}+a_{2k+1}\right) - c\,a_{2\lfloor m/2\rfloor+1}\right|\leq\left|\sum_{k=n}^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor} a_{2k}+a_{2k+1}\right| +\left| \,a_{2\lfloor m/2\rfloor+1}\right|<2\varepsilon.
$$
So the tails of the series $\sum a_k$ go to zero, and so the series is convergent.