# Proof verification $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{1}{n}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

My proof:
The convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{1}{n}$ is equivalent to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{n}$ converging.

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4} \cdots = \frac{1}{1\cdot 2}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 4} + \cdots =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n)}< \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}< \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} 
\end{equation}

It is well know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, and in the third term of the equation we see, that it is strictly increasing, hence it must also converge. QED.

I would like to know, whether or not this proof is correct, and how I could make it more professional? Maybe rigorous is the word I'm looking for

Comment: Simply apply Leibniz's criteria for alternating series.

Comment: Also relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/245095

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not correct. You are assuming that a series$$a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6+\cdots$$converges if and only if the series$$(a_1+a_2)+(a_3+a_4)+(a_5+a_6)+\cdots$$converges. This is not true. For instance, the series$$1-1+1-1+1-1+\cdots$$diverges, whereas the series$$(1-1)+(1-1)+(1-1)+\cdots$$converges. I suggest that you apply the alternating series test here.

Comment: Note that we can do this if we have a summable family. It breaks down here because  the series does not converge absolutely.

Comment: @Lelouch Since the problem was to show that $\sum a_n$ converges, your comment seems to amount to "note that it converges if it converges"..

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Maybe this was not the best way to formulate it. I wanted to say that if the series only had positive terms, then it would be possible to use this kind of tricks.

Comment: Are they really assuming the (and only if) part? Unless I'm mistaken they're not.

Comment: @samerivertwice In fact, the OP was only assuming that if $(a_1+a_2)+(a_3+a_4)+\cdots$ converges, then $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+\cdots$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

As said above, you can not regroup the terms of the series 2 by 2. Other possibilities for showing that this series converges are :

- Using the alternating series test
- Try to find a more elementary proof

As the one you proposed is not good (because the series converges conditionally and not absolutely), I propose you this proof that does not use the criteria :

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(-1)^{n+1} }{n} &=  -\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{(-1)^{n} }{n} \\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^{N}(-1)^{n}\int_0^1 x^{n-1} dx  \\
&= \int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^{N} (-x)^{n-1} dx \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{1-(-x)^{N}}{1-(-x)} dx \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x} dx - \int_0^1 \frac{(-x)^{N}}{1+x}dx \\
&= \ln(2) - \int_0^1 \frac{(-x)^{N}}{1+x}dx \\
\end{align}

Then we can show that the second integral converges towards $0$ when $N$ grows to infinity :
$$ |\int_0^1 \frac{(-x)^{N}}{1+x}dx| \leq \int_0^1 x^{N}dx = \frac{1}{N+1} \to 0$$

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, convergence of $(a_1+a_2)+(a_3+a_4)+\dots$ does not imply convergence of $\sum a_n$. Except it's easy to show that here it does:

> > **Prop.** If $(a_1+a_2)+(a_3+a_4)+\dots$ converges and $a_n\to0$ then $\sum a_n$ converges.

Partial Proof: Say $s_n=a_1+\dots a_n$ and $\sigma_k=(a_1+a_2)+\dots+(a_{2k-1}+a_{2k})$. We need to show that if $\sigma_k\to s$ and $a_n\to0$ then $s_n\to s$.

I leave the actual proof of that to you; it begins "Let $\epsilon>0$".

Note that if $n=2k$ then $s_n=\sigma_k$, while if $n=2k+1$ then $s_n=\sigma_k+a_{2n+1}$.

Comment: Indeed: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/245095, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/834210. I wonder if the question should be closed as a duplicate.